# Extracting above-ground part from Multipatch buildings with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, 3d-analyst

I have a lot of 3D buildings in Multipatch format (the grey features in the screenshot) and need to extract the building parts above ground.

I thought it should be possible to interpolate 2D buildings with z-values from a DEM (the green features in the screenshot), extrude the resulting PolygonZ features by a fixed height (e.g. 100 m) and use the intersection of the original buildings with the extruded buildings. But I do not find an option to extrude PolygonZ features. I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1.

Edit: my ultimate goal is to calculate the above-ground volume of each building.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why does it look like a staircase? In order to extrude the buildings, you can try extruding the Ground Elevation surface.

Comment: @Yogi These two are terraced buildings, hence the staircase look. Do you mean something like adding +200m to the DEM raster and creating a new TIN from it? How do I then get to the above-ground building?

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution. Since I ultimately only need the above-ground *volume*, not necessarily the geometry, the following works:

1. Create a high resolution TIN
2. Add z_min information to 3D buildings ("Add Z Information")
3. Create footprint of the 3D buildings ("Multipatch Footprint")
4. Calculate the volume between footprint ("Height field" = z_min) and TIN ("Polygon Volume")
5. Above-ground volume = full volume - underground volume from step 4

Though I don't like the need to use a TIN.